# jQuery .is(":disabled") - Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/hw4bz89k/

Why doesn't the following return 'true'? I know I must be missing something elementary.

```js
var test = $("#test");
test.prop("disabled", true);
alert(test.is(":disabled"));
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: if at all you want to add disabled for some validation reason or any testing purpose check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hw4bz89k/2/)**

Comment: Just keep in mind that it doesn't work with `prop`. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hw4bz89k/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot `disable` a `<div>` element.

From the jQuery doc for [**:disable**](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

> The `:disabled` selector should only be used for selecting HTML elements that support the disabled attribute (`<button>`, `<input>`, `<optgroup>`, `<option>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`).